# Where to create "Service layer"?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Jason Dolinger in his video replaces `StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"` with a method `OnStartup`. In this method he creates kind of "service layer".

Is it best place to create "Service layer"? So good-designed MVVM application should repalce `StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"` with custom `OnStartup` method where `service layer` should be created?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "service layer" and those that haven't seen the video probably won't either. Could you provide an example, maybe a snippit of Jason's code from the video?

Comment: A link to the video would also be good.

Comment: refer to answer in another my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187135/can-i-use-wcf-interface-as-a-mvvm-model. video is very popular, located here http://www.lab49.com/files/videos/Jason%20Dolinger%20MVVM.wmv (my question is from 0.59 to 1.04)

Comment: There is no big book of MVVM that we all refer back to in order to determine the "best" way we "should" implement something.  The answer to your question is "wherever it suits your needs."  In smaller apps, it probably doesn't matter.  In larger, you should probably be using some IoC or DI framework.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the old `static void main`. I delete the in VS created App.xaml, and go this way.

```
public class App : Application
{
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Init data/service layer etc.

        var app = new App();
        app.Run(new Window1()
        {
            DataContext = ...,
        });
    }
}
```